# Non ce la fai proprio a smettere, vero? - meaning

Tags: meaning

I heard the following question in a TV series:

> Non ce la fai proprio a smettere, vero?

Context: A couple is discussing in the morning about the odd behavior of the husband. During the discussion, he keeps trying to light a cigarette with a lighter, but it doesn't work. The wife then changes the subject and say the sentence above, obviously referring to the smoking addiction of the husband.

The English subtitles say "You just can't quit, can you?". I know that "vero" is used in rhetoric questions, similar to the adjective "right" in English (or "can you" in the English subtitle of this example). However, I do not quite understand the rest of the translation.

- "fare a fare qualcosa" means "to be able to do something" ?
- What does "ce" mean here?

Comment: This particular use of _fare_ together with _ce_ and _la_ is fixed, to the point that some consider it a separate word: [_farcela_](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/farcela).

Comment: Si tratta del verbo pronominale [*farcela*](http://www.viv-it.org/percorsi-linguistico-didattici/verbi-pronominali).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Come si spiega sul [sito Vivit](http://www.viv-it.org/percorsi-linguistico-didattici/verbi-pronominali) dell'Accademia della Crusca, "farcela" è uno dei cosiddetti "verbi pronominali", che vengono descritti in questo  modo:

> In italiano esistono alcuni verbi che assumono un significato particolare quando si presentano con alcuni pronomi atoni, questi verbi si chiamano pronominali. Questi sono alcuni esempi: 
>   *aspettarsela = prevedere che qualcosa dovrà accadere
>
>   fottersene (volgare) = non avere interesse per qualcosa
>
>   fregarsene = non avere interesse per qualcosa
>
>   sentirsela = essere pronto a fare qualcosa
>
>   prendersela = arrabbiarsi
>
>   vedersela = affrontare qualcosa
>
>   farcela = riuscire in qualcosa
>
>   andarsene = andare via da un posto
>
>
>   Te la sei presa con me ieri? (= Ti sei arrabbiato con me ieri?)
>
>   No, non me la sono presa.
>
>
>   Me ne frego di quello che mi dicono gli altri.(= Non mi interessa quello che mi dicono gli altri).*

Quindi, il significato della frase della domanda sarebbe

> Non riesci proprio a smettere, vero?

Comment: I'm a little confused about the pronoun at the end of  some of these pronominal verbs. For instance, aspettarsela. AFAIK the "la" pronoun is not part of the pronominal verb. An example: Non mi aspettavo proprio questo regalo! (given in https://www.wordreference.com/iten/aspettare). On the other hand, the pleonastic "ne" seems required/usual with fregarsi, eg Quel dirigente se ne frega di tutti i dipendenti (given in https://www.wordreference.com/iten/fregare)

Comment: @AlanEvangelista: Your example doesn't correspond to "aspettarsela". An example would be: "Questa non me l'aspettavo!"

Comment: I know. My question is: isn't the meaning of "aspettarsi" the same in the two sentences?  "Non mi aspettavo proprio questo regalo" = I really didn't expect this gift. "Questa non me l'aspettavo" = "Questa non mi aspettavo" = I didn't expect this. The only difference seems to be the (pleonastic and thus optional) pronoun "la".

Comment: @AlanEvangelista: You can't say "Questa non mi aspettavo". You must say "Questa non me l'aspettavo" or "Non mi aspettavo questo". Another example from [this book](https://books.google.es/books?id=5tDlCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT60&lpg=PT60&dq=%22non+me+la+sarei+aspettata%22&source=bl&ots=ofGIngKhuR&sig=ACfU3U2G2Qa1qbKN9QgOohLZGU48gtnGww&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjCm_Wln6rlAhUJhxoKHTmPAQcQ6AEwBHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22non%20me%20la%20sarei%20aspettata%22&f=false): "In fin dei conti non me la sarei aspettata diversa". It's an idiomatic use and pronoun "la" is compulsory.