# "Se ne va": how was it constituted?

Tags: grammar

Can someone explain how "se ne va" (leaves) is constituted? I guess the "va" is from the word "go" ,"ne" is "of it"? "Se"? Would love to understand it.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! I think your question is a duplicate of this one:   https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/11422.

Comment: Is the answer to the above linked question enough explanation to you? Please, let us know.

Comment: Thanks a lot it was indeed what i was looking for :-)

Comment: So, @LovelsHere, can we close this post as duplicate?

Comment: Yes Charo. Thank you.